# Unrefrigerated Mashed Bananas: Are they safe to bake with?

Tags: baking, food-safety, bananas

If mashed bananas are accidentally left on the counter overnight can they still be used for baking?

Comment: Biggest question is: Are they freshly mashed, or defrosted mashed bananas? If the latter: No. Otherwise I'm tempted to say "most likely, but taste a bit first". But I'm not an expert on these matters and not shy of trying if I know it's not going to kill me.

Comment: I recommend smelling them first. If they still smell like bananas, rather than vinegar or something rancid, I agree with @WillemvanRumpt about tasting. If they have a pure banana taste, I'd be more inclined to use them in something fully cooked. I have no documentation about safety, though, so this is my opinion. Also, sometimes my open bananas attract little fruit flies. If I see those, I immediately throw everything away!

Comment: Probably, but yuck!

Comment: If the bowl was covered, preferably well sealed with cling film in contact with the whole surface... It wouldn't have been oxidized or exposed to fruit flies... Should it not smell like alcohol or vinegar, I believe it's fine to bake with... 180℃ kills a hosts of germs IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

I hate wasting, so I get why you are asking this, lol!

I agree with "osp"... SMELL it. Sour or fishy or not like banana, well, then your banana bread might taste like something sour or fishy or not like banana.

Easiest solution is to just scoop off the top layer of the mashed banana that was exposed to the air!